# I can define the length of an array using a constant, so why doesn't int d[b] work?

Tags: c++

```cpp
int a = 5;
const int b = a, c = 4;

int e[a];
int d[b];
int f[c];
```

The definition of `f[c]` is valid.
The variable `b` is also a constant `int`, but the compiler gave me the error *"expression must have a constant value"* for the line `int d[b]`. What are the differences between `b` and `c`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> what are the differences between b and c?

c has a compile time constant initialiser, while b does not. A const object with compile time constant initialiser is itself a compile time constant value.

> Since I can define an lenth of an arry using a constant ,so why don't this work?

Not just any constant will do. `const` qualifier implies runtime constness (i.e the value may be determined at runtime but won't change throughout the lifetime of the object). Only compile time constant values can be used as array size.

Answer (score 6):

You are using a non-constant variable to assign value to a constant. Therefore, that variable's value **can't be determined compile time**. I know you aren't changing `a`, but the compiler does not think like this.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler diagnostic should really be *compile time evaluable constant expression*.

Since the original object to which `b` is assigned is not `const`, `b` is not a compile time evaluable constant expression, so compilation will fail as variable length arrays are not supported in standard C++.

Answer (score 1):

The "const" just only means that the variable will not change at run time, and does not mean that its value can be deduced at compiling time.

I guess what you are looking for is "constexpr".
Maybe you can try it out like this:

```
constexpr int b = 4; // can't be assigned from a!
int d[b];
```

The "constexpr" instead means a "real const" and the "const" only means "non-changing var", because some historical reason.
It must be mind that a native array in c++ always is fixed-length as @Bathsheba said.

Comment: What "other languages" are you talking about?

Comment: @Brian Sorry, it is not relevant. I changed my answer.

Comment: "No true scotsman..." - let me disagree with your *"constexpr" instead means a "real const" and the "const" only means "non-changing var"* statement. "const" means "const", "constexpr" means "constexpr" - they have two distinct meanings and implications in the context of the c++ language. "const" means ["Object cannot be modified"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv), "constexpr" means ["it is possible to evaluate the value of the function or variable at compile time"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I expressed it incorrectly. English is not my mother-tongue.

Answer (score 1):

The term "constant" is really ambiguous, and the keyword `const` is misleading.

`const` means: "don't allow this object's value won't be changed after initialisation". It does *not* mean "compile-time constant". Its initial value can (and usually does) still come from runtime sources.

You need a compile-time constant for an array bound.

It is sometimes possible to have an object named `foo` that is compile-time constant, if it is `const` *and* it was initialised from a constant expression, like a literal or a `constexpr` thing. That's the case for `c`; it is not the case for `b`.